# ¿Cómo devolver valores de tipo varchar, ingresando valores de tipo int en la columna de una tabla ya creada?

Tags: sql-server, function

Estoy intentando realizar una función que me convierta lo que ingrese en números en una palabra específica. Tengo una columna llamada mes de una tabla, de tipo entero. Se me pidió que se me fuera visible en lugar de números, el nombre del mes pero sin cambiar el tipo de valor de esa columna.

Por ejemplo, la idea es que dentro de los inserts de la tabla, en esa columna "Mes" ponga 1, pero al dar select de esta tabla o vista aparezca el nombre de mes "Enero" y así sucesivamente con los otros meses del año.

De momento así tengo mi función que se me es imposible ejecutar, no tengo claro muy bien como sería la sintaxis y también aprovechando para saber que podría agregar o si debería realizar algo más dentro de la misma, porque como dije, me debe retornar en tipo varchar. Espero haberme dado a explicar.

```
create function f_nombreMes
(
@MES int
)
returns varchar(30)
as
begin 
declare @NOMBREMES int
set @NOMBREMES = @MES
select 
      Case @NOMBREMES
      when 1 then 'Enero'
      when 2 then 'Febrero'
      when 3 then 'Marzo'
      when 4 then 'Abril'
      when 5 then 'Mayo'
      when 6 then 'Junio'
      when 7 then 'Julio'
      when 8 then 'Agosto'
      when 9 then 'Septiembre'
      when 10 then 'Octubre'
      when 11 then 'Noviembre'
      when 12 then 'Diciembre' end
return @NOMBREMES
end
```

Comment: por qué complicar tanto el tema?, lo más fácil sería que tuvieras en efecto un campo de fecha como tal, y obtener el nombre desde las funciones de SQL Server. Por otro lado, podrías usar un código como este: `Select DateName( month , DateAdd( month , NumeroDelMesAca, 0 ) - 1 )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No entiendo porque dices que no puedes usarla de momento.

Una pequeña mejora a la función, que ya estaba bien. Devolvemos el tamaño máximo que tiene el texto del mes. 10. No declaramos, ni usamos variables no necesarias. Directamente devolvemos sobre la entrada. Aquí un inciso,

```
create or alter function f_nombreMes
(
@MES int
)
returns varchar(10)
as
begin 
    return (select 
      Case @MES
        when 1 then 'Enero'
        when 2 then 'Febrero'
        when 3 then 'Marzo'
        when 4 then 'Abril'
        when 5 then 'Mayo'
        when 6 then 'Junio'
        when 7 then 'Julio'
        when 8 then 'Agosto'
        when 9 then 'Septiembre'
        when 10 then 'Octubre'
        when 11 then 'Noviembre'
        when 12 then 'Diciembre' 
        else ''
        end)
end;
```

Ahora la prueba.

```
drop table if exists dbo.ejemplo;
Create table dbo.ejemplo (id int identity(1,1), mes int)
Insert into dbo.ejemplo (mes)
values
(1),
(2),
(3),
(4),
(5),
(6),
(7),
(8),
(9),
(10),
(11),
(12),
(null);
```

Y la ejecución, en una select.

```
select *
     , dbo.f_nombreMes
       ( ejemplo.mes ) as mesLetra
       FROM dbo.ejemplo;
```

[image: Res]

Pero además de lo ya expresado, también puedes usar campos calculados. Esto requiere de modificar la tabla.

***Calculado.***

```
Alter table dbo.ejemplo
Add mesLetra As dbo.f_nombreMes(mes);
```

Como ves, se añade una columna que apunta a la función anterior, pasándole la columna `mes`.

```
select * from dbo.ejemplo;
```

[image: Res2]

Entre bambalinas, el motor aplica la función, cada vez que se hace una `select`.

[Campos calculados o persistidos](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2022/06/19/campos-calculados-o-persistidos/)

Comment: Me ha sido de gran ayuda tu aporte. Pude dar solución a mi requerimiento, te agradezco mucho.

Answer (score 0):

Yo creo que estás haciendo trabajo de más. En el caso de **SQLServer** ya dispones de lo necesario para extraer el nombre de un mes sin necesidad de funciones extra.

Puedes utilizar la función `DATENAME`, [como aquí se describe](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/datename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

De esta forma, una SQL como esta:

```
select fecha from tabla1
```

Que te devolvería este resultado:

[image: Tabla con campo SQL]

Puedes convertira en una como esta:

```
select fecha, DATENAME(MONTH, fecha) AS MES from tabla1
```

Que te devolvería este:

[image: Campo SQl de tipo fecha y el mes en formato cadena]

**NOTA:** Hay que tener en cuenta en este caso, que obtendrás *los nombres utilizando el idioma configurado en el servidor SQL*. Eso es lo recomendable (o no) según lo que quieras obtener en cada caso.